# CodeAcademy Pi Function

Tags: python, pi

This is my code...it errors out on line 5 and I don't know why. Thanks for the help in advance.

The error is invalid syntax.

```
from math import pi

radius = int(raw_input(("What radius would you like?"))

def area_of_circle(radius):
       return (radius ** 2) * math.pi

area_of_circle(radius)
```

Comment: Please remember that it's always helpful to include the *actual* text of the error message you get when posting your question.

Comment: The situation here is that there are *two* problems with your code as posted: The obvious one with `math` and the less obvious one with the extra `(`. By including the FULL text of the error message in your question, it allows experienced Python programmers to pinpoint the problem quickly. Otherwise, people have to guess and that just takes more effort for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
from math import pi
```

just use

```
import math
```

`from math import pi` loads the math module, but instead of assigning the module to the name `math`, it looks up `pi` in the module and assigns that to the name `pi`. This can be convenient, but it can also cause horrible initialization order issues.

Comment: So 'import math' then 'pi = math.pi'?

Comment: @RobB.: If you really want to use it with the bare name `pi`, use `from math import pi` and then refer to just `pi`. I recommend using `import math` and `math.pi`, though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing a closing parenthesis on line 2. But as Marius mentioned, you don't actually need those parentheses.

```
from math import pi

radius = int(raw_input("What radius would you like?")) # Parenthesis removed

def area_of_circle(radius):
       return (radius ** 2) * math.pi

area_of_circle(radius)
```

On top of that, you should also look at the suggestion by @user2357112 and use `import math` and `math.pi`. The updated code will look like:

```
import math # Not import pi

radius = int(raw_input("What radius would you like?")) # Parenthesis removed

def area_of_circle(radius):
       return (radius ** 2) * math.pi

# Printing here for feedback
print area_of_circle(radius)
```

Comment: It's not actually a missing closing parenthesis, it's an extra opening parenthesis in `raw_input`

Answer (score 1):

it works fine

```
import math

radius = int(raw_input(("What radius would you like?")))

def area_of_circle(radius):
       return (radius ** 2) * math.pi

print area_of_circle(radius)
```

you were missing ")" close parenthesis and the imported library should be math not pi.

Answer (score -1):

```
import math
#parameter

radius = int(input("Enter the radius: "))

def AreaOfCircle(radius):
    return (radius**2)*math.pi

print(AreaOfCirle(radius))
```